# ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths: How to eager load?

Tags: sinatra, eager-loading, activesupport

I'm using ActiveSupport in a sinatra project, and following the advice of some peers I've been using ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths to ease the loading of my classes in development. Now I'm approaching deployment day, and I don't exactly how to eager load them. In Rails that'd be easy: one would just set config.cache_classes = true and go about his way. But in a Sinatra app, I fail to see how to eager load them.